# How to search for two different expressions in linux

Tags: regex, linux, sed, grep

I have a file that contains some text like:

```
aaa.co
bbb.com
ccc.net
sss.co.uk
```

I need to extract the `*.co.*` and `*.com.*` and put them in another file. I used the following to extract the `*.com.*` but how can I make extracting `*.com.*` and `*.co.*` in one command instead of performing them separately ?

```
egrep -io '[a-z0-9\-]+\.com(\.[a-z]{2})?' input.txt | sed -e 's/www.//' | sort | uniq >output.txt
```

Input file example:

```
aaa.co
bbb.com
ccc.net
sss.co.uk
```

Result file:

```
co
com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just make the m in com optional

```
egrep -io '[a-z0-9\-]+\.co(m)?(\.[a-z]{2})?' input.txt | sed -e 's/www.//' | sort | uniq >output.txt
```

**edit:**
you could also drop sed and uniq

```
awk 'match($0, "(www\\.)?([a-z0-9\\-]+\\.com?(\\.[a-z]{2})?)", r) { print r[2] }' input.txt | sort -u
```

**edit:** 
another way to loose sed and uniq

```
grep -oP '^(www\.)?\K[a-z0-9\-]+\.com?(\.[a-z]{2})?(?=)$' input.txt | sort -u
```

Comment: Hi @rbtux Good idea to drop `sed` and `uniq`. But the `sed` script removes `www.` However the `awk` script adds `www.` isn't it? (`awk` script should be fixed...)

Comment: hum... you are very skilled about `awk`, but you are right, it is not really human readable... I am thinking about a global `sed` script instead of the `awk` script...

Comment: please have a look on my answer based on `sed` ;-) I did not know we could use `perl` pattern with `grep`. I like your answer, very good :-D  => +1

Comment: Oops, I have copy-pasted the wrong command line :-/ thank you @rbtux for attention ;-) I have just updated my answer (I also use `sed` 4.2.1)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19689/discussion-between-olibre-and-rbtux)

Answer (score 2):

### `grep` and `egrep`

The command line from your question keeps `.com`, `.co` and `.co.uk`. Therefore, in this section I give two basic examples using `grep` and `egrep`. These command line keep the full [top-level domain (TLD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain), as the command line in your question does it:

```
grep -io 'com?(\.[a-z]{2})?$' input.txt | sort -u >output.txt
```

or more understandable:

```
egrep -io 'com$|co$|co[.][a-z]{2}$' input.txt | sort -u >output.txt
```

For your information, `egrep "PATTERN1|PATTERN2"` is the same as `grep -E "PATTERN1|PATTERN2"`

### Alternative using `sed`

The following `sed` command line does not keep the full [top-level domain (TLD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) because your question specifies to keep `co` when processing `*.co.uk`

```
sed -n '/[a-z.][.]com\?/s/.*[.]\(com\?\)\(.*\|$\)/\1/p' input.txt | sort -u >output.txt
```

### Explanations

- `-n` => do not print
- process lines matching pattern `/[.]com?[.]/` only
- `s/.*[.]\(com?\)([.][a-z]{2})?/\1/` => substitute the line by `com` or `co`
- `p` => finally prints the line

### Testing the command line

`input.txt`:

```
aaa.co
bbb.com
ccc.net
sss.co.uk
www.zzz.co
www.yyy.com
www.xxx.co.tw
```

Test based on `uniq -c`:

```
sed -n '/[a-z.][.]com\?/s/.*[.]\(com\?\)\(.*\|$\)/\1/p' input.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

Result:

```
  4 co
  2 com
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give multiple `-e` options to any `grep`

```
egrep -e '\.com\.' -e '\.co\.' ...
```

or grep for an alternative

```
egrep -io '[a-z0-9\-]+\.(com|co)(\.[a-z]{2})?' input.txt | ...
```

or in this special case make "m" optional

```
egrep -io '[a-z0-9\-]+\.com?(\.[a-z]{2})?' input.txt | ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/.*\.\(com\?\)\.\?.*/s//\1/p;d' file | sort -u
```